# Where is the Green Room?

Tags: supernatural, behind-the-scenes, real-location

I'm watching *Supernatural* for the first time and just saw the episode "Lucifer Rising". In it there is a room, the Green Room, that's super fancy looking with white walls, gold accents/trimmings, and infinity mirrors, and they place a bunch of burgers on a platter for Dean.

From the [wiki](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Lucifer_Rising):

> Dean finds himself transported to what appears to be a luxurious hotel room - referred to as the Green Room by Zachariah.

[image]

Where is this fancy room? Or was it a set built just for the show? What's the location it was shot at?
**Where was this scene shot (in real life, out of universe)?**

Comment: Have you seen past this episode in the show?

Comment: In the theater and live TV, the green room is where actors and guests wait before going on stage.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist No, I have not. :)

Answer (score 2):

**In universe:** The Green Room is located in Van Nuys, California in an abandoned building. Angels like Zachariah and Castiel took Dean Winchester and Adam Milligan
to the beautiful green room to secure vessel for Michael.

**Out of universe:** The entire show is shot in Canada as it is much more cheaper than shooting in the USA. The green room/beautiful room is a filming set in British Columbia, Canada.

Sources: [SupernaturalWiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Green_Room) and [IMDB Supernatural location's.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/locations)

Comment: "its just a set somewhere in hollywood made entirely by the director's imagination." sources? How do you 'know' this?

Comment: Let me switch on my pc to edit and improve this answer

Comment: @RedCaio sorry I was wrong about the hollywood part.